# Input file with info separated by commas

Tags: arrays, input, char, double, strtok

How can I read an input file that has strings and doubles separated by commas with multiple lines. I want to keep the strings in a 2D array like `char Teams[5][40]`. I want to do the same for each row of numbers. So for the second row of numbers I want `char probFG[5][10]` and the third row `probTD [5][10]`.

I want each number to be stored in a different index of the array but I want to make sure the all indexes of each array to correspond to their respective columns.

```
Team1,0.80,0.30
Team1,0.30,0.20
Team1,0.20,0.70
Team1,0.70,0.80
Team1,0.90,0.20
```

How would you do this while taking into consideration the use of string stream because I would like to use the numbers later on? Basically how to you use char arrays in accordance to string streams.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @Virtlink i guess C because the strtok tag

Answer (score 0):

Well i asume the language is `C`, here is the code that i think you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdlib>

const int N = 100000;

static char buffer[N]; //buffer to read the user input
static char Teams[N][40];
static char probFG[N][10];
static char probTD[N][10];

int main ()
{
    FILE *file = fopen("myFile.txt","r"); //open the file(i assume is a txt)
    int lineIndex = 0; //keep track of the current row

    //reading the file
    while(fscanf(file,"%s",buffer) != EOF) {
        int index = 0; //this int keep the track of the current column
        char * pch;
        pch = strtok (buffer,",");
        while (pch != NULL) { //split the string
            //printf("%s\n",pch);
            if(index == 0) 
                strcpy(Teams[lineIndex],pch);
            else if(index == 1)
                strcpy(probFG[lineIndex],pch);
            else
                strcpy(probTD[lineIndex],pch);
            pch = strtok (NULL, ",");

            index++;
        }

        lineIndex++;
    }

    //if you want to convert the char to float use this function
    //as an example here is the sum of the first two numbers in the first row
    double a = atof(probFG[0]);
    double b = atof(probTD[0]);

    double c = a + b;

    printf("%lf\n",c);

    return 0;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: if you think my answer is correct please accept it, any doubt you can ask me